# How to fix a "stale element reference" when trying to check if an element is displayed?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I would like to simply click on my delete button, then to check if it's always displayed (failed test), or if it disappeared (passed test). I tried 2 methods but neither worked.

Here is my code:

```
# Find and click on the Delete button 

deleteButton = driver.find_element('xpath','//button[@class="added-manually btn btn-info"][contains(text(),"Delete")]')
deleteButton.click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Check Delete button not displayed anymore

Method 1:

```
if deleteButton.is_displayed():
    print("Oh no ! Delete button is always present x_x")
else:
    print("Good ! Delete button is not present anymore")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Projets Python\Python Basics\tests\Selenium web\add_remove_elements.py", line 35, in <module>
    if deleteButton.is_displayed():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hendb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 252, in is_displayed
    return self.parent.execute_script(f"/* isDisplayed */return ({isDisplayed_js}).apply(null, arguments);", self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hendb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 405, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {"script": script, "args": converted_args})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hendb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 345, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\hendb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found
  (Session info: chrome=116.0.5845.96); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#stale-element-reference-exception
```

Method 2:

```
if len(deleteButton.text)>0:
    print("Yes, the button is not present anymore !")
else:
    print("Ohh, the button is always displayed x_x")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Projets Python\Python Basics\tests\Selenium web\add_remove_elements.py", line 33, in <module>
    print("Yes, the button is not present anymore !")
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hendb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 90, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hendb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 395, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hendb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 345, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\hendb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found
  (Session info: chrome=116.0.5845.96); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#stale-element-reference-exception
```

Answer (score 1):

As per 'Stale Element' defination:
Stale Element means an old element or no longer available element.

Means element you are trying to interact is no longer present, so yes, button is not displaying..
In order to overcome this exception, you can use exception-handling for this, in such a way:

```
try:
    deleteButton.is_displayed()

except StaleElementReferenceException:
    print("Button is not displaying")
```

Comment: Thank you :). This code works. I just completed by adding a print in the "try" part.

try:
    deleteButton.is_displayed()
    print ("Button is displayed")
except StaleElementReferenceException:
    print("Button is not displayed")

Comment: You are welcome.. Can you please tick the answer, so that others know about this.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods do not work because you save reference to a button when it exists and then attempt to query property of that button when it is removed from DOM.

Your choice could be to use **Expected Conditions** here.

after `deleteButton.click()` you could use something like this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(
    ec.invisibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//button[@class="added-manually btn btn-info"][contains(text(),"Delete")]')
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work either. I'm trying other solutions.